# Infinite family of finite groups without surjections

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there an infinite family $\mathcal{F}$ of finite groups such that

- their exponent is bounded, i.e. $\exists N \geq 1 : \forall x \in G \in \mathcal{F}, x^N = 1_G$;
- there does not exist any surjective morphism between two distinct groups in $\mathcal{F}$?

(Without the bound on the order, {$\mathbb{Z}/(p) \mid p$ prime} is an obvious solution.)

Comment: Given any positive integer $M$ we easily find a family of $M+1$ groups: $C_2^k\times C_3^{M-k}$, $k=0,1,2,\ldots,M$ with $N=6$. But infinitely many...???

Comment: It's not gonna be possible to extend this kind of construction by direct products of a fixed set of groups to an infinite family, because of [Dickson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson's_lemma) applied to the family of exponent tuples. That was something I tried…

Comment: Yeah, the number of simple groups that can appear as composition factors of the groups in $\mathcal{F}$ should be finite. Then each individual composition series appears in only finitely many non-isomorphic groups, and I might suspect the answer to be negative, but I am certainly not betting on it.

Comment: The idea would then be, assuming the family $\mathcal{F}$ exists, that there must exist a simple group $G_0$ that is a homomorphic image of infinitely many groups in the family. Then continue with groups $G$ fitting into an exact sequence $1\to S\to G\to G_0\to1$, $S$ simple, that are homomorphic images of groups in $\mathcal{F}$ etc. But I don't see a way of running such an induction to a conclusion :-(